# .insertcrossreference method deleting space before reference in word document when entered

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some code that searches through a document for some unique text "(cross reference Table 2.1)", and then replaces that text with a cross reference to Table 2.1. The code works well, except that in one section of the document, inserting the cross reference actually deletes the space " " before the cross reference. For instance the original text reading "refer (cross reference Table 2.1)" becomes "referTable2.1" when it should read "refer Table2.1". This only happens in one location in the document, and there doesn't seem to be any reason why this is happening (i.e. there are no extra " " in my code or word template where there shouldn't be).

```
Public Sub Master()
    Call ReplaceTextWithCrossReferenceToTable(wrdDoc, _
        "(cross reference Table 2.1)", "Table 2.1", wrdApp)
End Sub

Sub ReplaceTextWithCrossReferenceToTable(wrdDoc As Word.Document, _
        ReferenceText As String, ReferenceSource As String, _
        wrdApp As Word.Application)

    Dim wrdTables As Variant, intTableNames As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer, RefValue As Integer
    wrdTables = wrdDoc.GetCrossReferenceItems("Table")
    For intTableNames = 1 To UBound(wrdTables)
        If InStr(wrdTables(intTableNames), ReferenceSource) Then
            RefValue = intTableNames
        End If
    Next i
    If RefValue = 0 Then Exit Sub
    With wrdDoc.Content.Find
        .Text = ReferenceText
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = 0
        Do While .Execute
            k = k + 1
        Loop
    End With
    For j = 1 To k
        With wrdApp.Selection
            .Find.Text = ReferenceText
            .Find.Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
            .Find.Execute FindText:=ReferenceText
            .Delete
            .InsertCrossReference "Table", wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, RefValue, True
        End With
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a bit of a guess based on what I would do in Excel...and perhaps I'm missing something, but instead of *all* of your code, couldn't you do it with a single line using the Replace Function, something like `wrdDoc.Content = Replace(wrdDoc.Content,"(cross reference Table 2.1)", "Table 2.1")`...?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that would only replace the text with text. I need to insert a cross reference with a hyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a test for the presence of a space character.

```
If not <range>.Previous(unit:=wdWord).Characters.Last = Chr$(32) Then
    <range>.InsertBefore text = Chr$(32)
End If
```

Where you'd replace  with the range that represents the cross reference you've just inserted.

Comment: If Not .Previous(Unit:=wdWord).Characters.Last = Chr$(32) Then
                    .InsertBefore Chr$(32)
                    .MoveRight
                End If     Thanks, that worked after a bit of tweaking